# Design Patterns Unity3D?

Tags: unity3d

Bom dia,

Comecei a trabalhar com `Unity3D`, estava tudo indo bem, até que vi os meus códigos ficarem GIGANTES, então resolvi separar tudo direitinho em uma `design pattern` "própria", criei três camadas para separar os `scripts`. `Model`, para modelar os `GameObjects`.

```
public class PlayerModel {
    public GameObject PlayerGameObject { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Life { get; set; }

    public PlayerMode() { 
        this.PlayerGameObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player"); 
    }
}

public class PlayerService {
    private PlayerModel playerModel;

    void recoveryLife(int quantity) {
        playerModel.Life += quantity;
    }

    public PlayerService(PlayerModel _playerModel) {
        this.playerModel = _playerModel; 
    }
}

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour{
    public GameObject player;
    public PlayerModel playerModel;
    public PlayerService playerService;

    void Start() {
        playerModel = new PlayerModel();
        playerModel.Name = "Personagem";
        playerModel.Life = 100;

        playerService = new PlayerService(playerModel);
    }
}
```

`Services`, para fazer as ações do `GameObject` (atacar, receber dano, andar, etc) e uma `Controller`, que faz a chamada de ambas. No entanto, ao meu entender, as `controllers` podem ter ciência de outro `GameObject`, no entanto a model e a service SÓ podem saber delas mesmas?

Resumindo, alguém teria algum tutorial, exemplo de Design Pattern pra Unity?

Obrigado!

Comment: É um pouco difícil julgar sem ter uma visão mais concreta do que vc estava modelando. Se os seus códigos ficaram gigantes, existe a possibilidade de você não estar usando a própria Orientação a Objetos da maneira adequada. Tinha muita repetição de trechos de código? Havia potencial para alguma herança? Essas são perguntas que podem te ajudar.

Comment: A ideia das camadas pode ser boa ou não. Novamente, depende do que vc está modelando. Fazer as referências entre os objetos no Model e os objetos no Services (para que as ações possam ser invocadas neles) também tem o seu custo, *principalmente porque muitas das ações da API básica da Unity são diretamente relacionadas ao GameObject* (colisões, por exemplo). Dependendo do jogo, essa indireção Services -> Model pode ser um custo desnecessário.